# Replacement implies separation requires reflection

Tags: set-theory

Exercise II.5.13 in Kunen (2013) asks us to prove that there is a finite set of instances of comprehension which, together with the other axioms of ZF, proves all instances of comprehension. The hint says we use reflection to reduce quantification over $V$ to quantification over some $V_\alpha$. My argument though, and the others on this site, make no use of reflection. Can it be done without replacement, or is there a mistake in the proof below?

Given sets $x, a_1, \ldots, a_n$ and a formula $\phi(v_1, \ldots, v_{n+1})$. We want to show the existence of $\{ y \in x : \phi(a_1, \ldots, a_n, y) \}$.

If no element $y \in x$ satisfies $\phi(a_1, \ldots, a_n, y)$, then the empty set witnesses this instance of separation.

Otherwise, fix some $d \in x$ such that $\phi(a_1, \ldots, a_n, d)$, and define $\psi(v_1, \ldots, v_{n+2})$ by $( \phi(v_1, \ldots, v_{n+1}) \land v_{n+1} = v_{n+2}) \lor (( \neg \phi(v_1, \ldots, v_{n+1}) \land v_{n+2} = d))$. Applying replacement with $\psi$, we then get the set $\{ t : \exists y \in x \, \psi(a_1, \ldots, a_n, y, t) \}$, which witnesses separation.

Comment: You proved that for each $\phi$ there is a $\psi_\phi$ such that replacement applied to $\psi_\phi$ implies separation for $\phi$ (on appropriate parameters). This is not what the question is asking. What you need to do is to show that there are finitely many $\phi$, say $\phi_1,\dots,\phi_n$, such that reflection together with comprehension for $\phi_1,\dots,\phi_n$ implies comprehension for all other $\phi$.

Comment: We can prove that if $z \subset V$, then $z \in V$. Is there a way we can formalize this using only finitely many instances of separation, and then conclude that all instances of separation are provable?